# How to fill empty cells with a sequence of numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, interpolation, forecast

I have been facing this problem for a long time. Sometimes i get excel files that only some of cells have value and i need to fill empty cells with sequence of numbers.
for example see following:
[image]
In the example above, the first column contains the names and the first row contains the dates.
Take a look at row 31 to understand my problem. there are 2 empty cells before cell D31 and i must fill this cells with sequence of numbers. For example, the number 41500 is suitable for cell B31 and the number 41750 is suitable for cell C31. after cell D31, the number 42250 is suitable for cell E31 and the number 45266 is suitable for cell H31 **and all empty cells must be filled with appropriate numbers.**
I hope you understand what I mean because I cannot explain my problem better than this.
I can't use excel FORECAST feature because some rows like row 2 or 3 or 4 have high number of empty cells and if i use FORECAST feature i get following error:
[image]
i want to use this date in **flourish studio website** to create chart bar race. flourish studio website have interpolate feature for fill blank/empty cells but i don't know why that feature not working! **i need something like flourish studio website interpolate feature**
are there any idea for this problem?
my excel file(in csv format) for testing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EYnRotT7vahWygFp4Lk-BIfKACp3z-yF

Comment: Might want to explain exactly *why* those numbers are "suitable"?

Comment: @TimWilliams It is an example to understand how empty cells must fill. When we subtract the value of cell D31 from the value of cell F31, the number 500 is obtained. Half of the number 500 can be added to the number in cell D31. It might be better to start the interpolation from the first cell that has values in each row.

Comment: Judging by other rows containing all data we can conclude that your data is not linear, therefore Tim Williams question is very relevant. Filling the gaps with wrong assumptions leads to possible wrong decision making based on the data.

Comment: @P.b This data is will not use for important work! And they will not be considered in important decisions! This data will be used for personal purposes

Comment: If cell D31 already contains a number, then why are you changing it? Surely it is the empty cells that need numbers? Not the ones that have numbers. Perhaps you should consider filling cell E31 with D31 + (F31-D31)/2

Comment: @SolarMike I did not change cell D31!

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubt on the idea behind the question itself, but we could use MAKEARRAY combined with TREND (FORECAST can't work with dates in past):

```
=LET(all,     'asli(1)'!A1:GP72,
     data,    DROP(all,1,1),
     years,   DROP(TAKE(all,1),,1),
     country, DROP(TAKE(all,,1),1),
HSTACK(
       VSTACK("",
              country),
       VSTACK(years,
              MAKEARRAY( ROWS(data), COLUMNS(data),
                 LAMBDA( r,          c,
                         IF(INDEX(data,r,c),
                            INDEX(data,r,c),
                            LET(y,TOROW(years/(INDEX(data,r,)>0),3),
                                d,TOROW(INDEX(data,r,)/(INDEX(data,r,)>0),3),
                            TREND(d,y,INDEX(years,,c)))))))))
```

[image]

LET first declares some names we can use for reference in the formula:
`all` refers to the complete data set including the year header and country names.
`data` drops the years and names and leaves the range containing the data.
`years` is the header of the data (starting from column B).
`country` is the list of country names from the data (starting from row 2).

The HSTACK/VSTACK part stacks the headers for including them in the outcome, but the *filling of missing data*-part starts at `MAKEARRAY`:

MAKEARRAY checks for the current row/column of the `data` (`INDEX(data,r,c)` if it contains data.
If it does it will use that data,
else `y` filters out the `years` where the current row's `data` contains a value and `d` filters the `data` for current row where it contains a value.
These are used in `TREND`, where `d` are the `known_ys`, `y` are the `known_xs` and the `year` of that current column is the `new_x` : `TREND(d,y,INDEX(years,,c))`

I hope it helps with whatever you want to accomplish with it.

*Edit: in case of Excel 2021 you don't have access to some of the functions used in the solution above.
You could use the following in another tab in cell `B2` (dragged down to `B72`):*

```
=LET(rowdata,    'asli(1)'!B2:GP2,
     headerdata, 'asli(1)'!$B$1:$GP$1,
     n,          ISNUMBER(rowdata),
     x,          FILTER(headerdata,n),
     y,          FILTER(rowdata,n),
IF(n,
   rowdata,
   TREND(y,x,headerdata)))
```

*This will only calculate the data, I excluded the headers for this, but you can use `='asli(1)'!B1:GP2` in `B1` and `='asli(1)'!A2:A72` in `A2`.*

And for even older Excel use this in a new tab in Cell `B2` and drag down/right:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER('asli(1)'!B2),
    'asli(1)'!B2:GP2,
    TREND(
          INDEX('asli(1)'!2:2,,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN('asli(1)'!B2:GP2)/ISNUMBER('asli(1)'!B2:GP2),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER('asli(1)'!B2:GP2))))))),
          INDEX('asli(1)'!$1:$1,,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN('asli(1)'!B2:GP2)/ISNUMBER('asli(1)'!B2:GP2),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER('asli(1)'!B2:GP2))))))),
          'asli(1)'!B$1))
```

Comment: tnq very much - please tell me how to run your formula in excel - i enter your formula in A1 cell but not working. i think i enter your formula in wrong way. if it possible please record video from running formula and share here.

Comment: i think this formula is only for google sheets and office 365.

Comment: Office 365 is required for this formula. I created a new tab and referenced the existing sheet from there. But it would also work if you paste it after the last row of your data. If you don't have Office 365 let me know.

Comment: no i don't have office 365. i have only office 2021 and excel 2021

Comment: I edited my answer to also provide solutions for Excel 2021 and older.